# Pytest show whitespace and tabs in errors

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using `pytest` to run tests on my python scripts.

In one case I need to compare text output of a script which contains both spaces and tabs.

By default, `pytest` doesn't seem to use special characters for whitespace and tabs, which makes comparing errors very difficult.
Every time I have to copy the error into my editor to find the difference.

Is it possible to make `pytest` more distinctly represent invisible characters?

Here is what I mean:

[image: distinct invisible characters]

First line containing 4 spaces, second line has a tab and last line is empty.

Comment: Please proevide [MRC](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You should use following hook in your `conftest.py` file to define custom assertion failure output:

```py
TAB_REPLACEMENT = "[tab]"
SPACE_REPLACEMENT = "[space]"
def pytest_assertrepr_compare(config, op, left, right):
    left = left.replace(" ", SPACE_REPLACEMENT).replace("\t", TAB_REPLACEMENT)
    right = right.replace(" ", SPACE_REPLACEMENT).replace("\t", TAB_REPLACEMENT)
    return [f"{left} {op} {right} failed!"]
```

Test example:

```py
def test_1():
    assert "    " == "  "
```

Output:

```
=== test session starts ===
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

test.py F                                                                                                                                                                                                                  [100%]

=== FAILURES ===
___ test_1 ___

    def test_1():
>       assert "    " == "      "
E       assert [space][space][space][space] == [tab] failed!

test.py:2: AssertionError
=== short test summary info ===
FAILED test.py::test_1 - assert [space][space][space][space] == [tab] failed!
=== 1 failed in 0.20s ===
```

So you can replace `[tab]` and `[space]` with any symbol you want.

Comment: Do you by any chance know what the original logic is?
If I use `pytest_assertrepr_compare` then the error output is no longer formatted nicely, so makes it impossible to find error in long strings.

I would like to just replace characters, but keep original formatting.

Comment: Sure. Originally it has only one line: `return util.assertrepr_compare(config=config, op=op, left=left, right=right)`. `util` is imported like this `from _pytest.assertion import util`. Try to find it in `_pytest` package if you want source code of this method. `_pytest.assertion.util.assertrepr_compare` line 160 for pytest 7.2.0